# The proof of $A/m^n$ isomorphic to $\hat {A} /\hat {m}^n$

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

$A$ is a discrete valuation ring, $m$ its maximal ideal, $\hat A, \hat m$ their completion respectively.

In J.S. Milne's *Algebraic Number Theory*, p. 116:

[image]

Why the openness implies the surjective part?

What i think so far, given $x \in \hat A$, since $\hat A$ is an completion, there exists $a\in A$, such that $x-a=\pi^tu$ with $t$ big and $u \in \hat A \setminus \hat m^n$ which is closed,  but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Since $A/m^n$ is artinian the completion brings nothing new.